# Maximize points won by flipping coins

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, there is [this king-of-the-hill challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79136/45032) going on at PPCG SE to which I submitted [my participation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79153/45032). I won't change it further in terms of behaviour, so I wanted to know what you think of the code.

## The challenge

It is very well described in the original post, I'll just summarize the key ideas here.

### Setup

- A pile of \$C\$ unflipped coins at the center of the table;
- \$N\$ players around the table with, each, \$F_i\$ flipped coins and \$U_i\$ unflipped coins (\$i \in [0;N[\$)

### Input of the program

Single argument formated following:

$$R;I;C;P_i\_S_i\_F_i\_U_i;P_i\_S_i\_F_i\_U_i;\ldots$$

Where \$R\$ is the current round, \$I\$ is the id of our player, \$P_i\$ is the id of the player being described by the \$P\_S\_F\_U\$ data and \$S_i\$ is its score.

### Expected output

A 3-character string, nothing else, representing the actions of our player for this turn. The actions can be:

> `N`: Do Nothing
>   `1`: Take 1 coin from the central pile *[Effects: +1 local unflipped / -1 point / -1 global unflipped]*
>   `2`: Take 2 coins from the central pile *[Effects: +2 local unflipped / -2 points / -2 global unflipped]*
>   `3`: Take 3 coins from the central pile *[Effects: +3 local unflipped / -3 points / -3 global unflipped]*
>   `A`: Put back 1 coin from your pile *[Effects: -1 local unflipped / +1 point / +1 global unflipped]*
>   `B`: Put back 2 coins from your pile *[Effects: -2 local unflipped / +2 points / +2 global unflipped]*
>   `C`: Put back 3 coins from your pile *[Effects: -3 local unflipped / +3 points / +3 global unflipped]*
>   `X`: Remove 1 coin from your pile *[Effects: -1 local unflipped / 0 point]*
>   `Y`: Remove 2 coins from your pile *[Effects: -2 local unflipped / 0 point]*
>   `Z`: Remove 3 coins from your pile *[Effects: -3 local unflipped / 0 point]*
>   `R`: Rotate coins to previous player *[Effects: -1 point per unflipped received, +2 points per flipped received / applies to all players]*
>   `T`: Rotate coins to next player *[Effects: -1 point per unflipped received, +2 points per flipped received / applies to all players]*
>   `F`: Flip 1 coin *[Effects: -1 local unflipped / +1 local flipped / +2 point]*
>   `U`: Unflip 1 coin *[Effects: +1 local unflipped / -1 local flipped / -2 point]*

## The code

The submission tries every one of the 2744 possible move and output the (first) one with the maximum amount of points gained.

```
import sys
import itertools
from copy import deepcopy


MOVES_REQUIRED = 3

FLIPPED = 0
UNFLIPPED = 1


def filter_neighbors(neighbors, me, size):
    limit = size - MOVES_REQUIRED
    for data in neighbors:
        i, _, flipped, unflipped = map(int, data.split('_'))
        if MOVES_REQUIRED < (me - i) % size < limit:
            continue  # Skip neighbors that are too far away
        yield i, [flipped, unflipped]


class Player:
    def __init__(self, raw_data):
        _, me, coins, *data = raw_data.split(';')

        self.num_players = len(data)
        self._me = int(me)
        self._coins = int(coins)
        self._state = dict(filter_neighbors(data, self._me, self.num_players))

    def reset(self):
        self.me = self._me
        self.coins = self._coins
        self.state = deepcopy(self._state)
        self.my_state = self.state[self.me]

    def invalid_move(self, move):
        if move in 'NRT':
            return False

        if move in '123'[:self.coins]:
            return False

        flipped, unflipped = self.my_state
        if flipped and move == 'U':
            return False
        if unflipped and move == 'F':
            return False

        if move in 'AXBYCZ'[:2 * unflipped]:
            return False

        return True

    def N(self):
        return 0

    def one(self):
        self.coins -= 1
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] += 1
        return -1

    def two(self):
        self.coins -= 2
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] += 2
        return -2

    def three(self):
        self.coins -= 3
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] += 3
        return -3

    def A(self):
        self.coins += 1
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] -= 1
        return 1

    def B(self):
        self.coins += 2
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] -= 2
        return 2

    def C(self):
        self.coins += 3
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] -= 3
        return 3

    def X(self):
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] -= 1
        return 0

    def Y(self):
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] -= 2
        return 0

    def Z(self):
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] -= 3
        return 0

    def R(self):
        self.me = (self.me + 1) % self.num_players
        flipped, unflipped = self.my_state = self.state[self.me]
        return 2 * flipped - unflipped

    def T(self):
        self.me = (self.me - 1) % self.num_players
        flipped, unflipped = self.my_state = self.state[self.me]
        return 2 * flipped - unflipped

    def F(self):
        self.my_state[FLIPPED] += 1
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] -= 1
        return 2

    def U(self):
        self.my_state[FLIPPED] -= 1
        self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] += 1
        return -2

setattr(Player, '1', Player.one)
setattr(Player, '2', Player.two)
setattr(Player, '3', Player.three)


def scenarii(player):
    for tries in itertools.product('N123ABCXYZRTFU', repeat=MOVES_REQUIRED):
        player.reset()
        points = 0
        for try_ in tries:
            if player.invalid_move(try_):
                break
            points += getattr(player, try_)()
        else:
            yield points, ''.join(tries)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = Player(sys.argv[1])
    print(max(scenarii(player))[1])
```

What do you think?

Comment: Yo, I noticed this is your only unaccepted question. Is there something the answer is missing that you want answered is particular? If so I _may_ be able to help, :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz It's just that, as stated in the comments, I really dislike the hit on readability of the current answer. Otherwise, I don't have any particular wish, any and all aspects, as usual ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to expound on this answer later (when I'm on my Python 3 machine). To begin with, there's a lot of repeated logic, especially in the `one`, `two`, ... `C` methods. You can avoid this with a class method to generate these instance methods.

```
class Player:

    @classmethod
    def make_flipper(cls, name, val):
        def flipper(self):
            self.coins -= val
            self.my_state[UNFLIPPED] += val
            return -val
        setattr(cls, name, flipper)

    method_dict = {
        'N': 0,
        'one': 1,
        'two': 2,
        'three': 3,
        'A': -1,
        'B': -2,
        'C': -3
    }

    for name, val in method_dict.items():
        make_flipper(name, val)
```

Note that this is untested, I'll fix it when I get home if it's broken.

Comment: I do agree that we can do something to reduce the amount of repeated code, but I don't find this solution that readable. Plus the help on the class will be messed up, if we ever need to add docstrings...

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I agree with the readability comment. Regarding the docstring, this can be done programmatically on the wrapper function by setting `__doc__` IIRC. I'll try to think of another approach though, didn't end up having any time last night.